# How to fix If Statment in Python Whle Scraping

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

This Else Statement is working Half! if website and phone not found it will type N,N but the issue is if website and phone is **found** it will also write in new line N,N I Don't Like This

I Need Something Like This: If Website And Phone Not Found Type N,N and if website and phone found add new line add the second URL details

**ERROR:**

This Script is typing N,N when website and phone found and when not found it will type detail and make new line and add N,N

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import csv
import pandas
import itertools

with open("sans.csv",'r') as s:
    s.read()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/konomama-san-francisco?osq=Restaurants'

driver.get(url)
website_link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+ .link-size--default__373c0__1skgq')

phone = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.text--offscreen__373c0__1SeFX+ .text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_')

items = len(website_link)
with open("sans.csv", 'a', encoding="utf-8") as s:
    for combination in itertools.zip_longest(website_link, phone):
        s.write(f'{combination[0].text if combination[0] else "N"}, {combination[1].text if combination[1] else "N"}\n')
    else:
        s.write('N, N')

driver.close()

print("Done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the code a little and add `if` condition to check if the `combination` exists:

```
with open("sans.csv", 'a', encoding="utf-8") as s:
    for combination in itertools.zip_longest(website_link, phone):
        if combination:
            s.write(f'{combination[0] if combination[0] else "N"}, {combination[1] if combination[1] else "N"}\n')
        else:
            s.write('N, N\n')
```